# The meaning "get up to" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> — How did architect become involved?
>   — Well, someone had to design the dreams, right?
>   — Why don't you give us another five minutes?
>   — Five minutes? What--? We were talking for at least an hour.
>   — In a dream, your mind functions more quickly... therefore time seems to feel slower.
>   — Five minutes in the real world gives you an hour in a dream.
>   — Why don't you see what you can ***get up to*** in five minutes.

I've found the meaning of *get up to* [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/search/?direct=1&multi=1&dictCode=english&q=get%20up%20to) but I can't understand how it can be bounded with that context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a transcription of dialog from the movie *Inception.*

In this case, it may help you to look at the original script:

> **Ariadne:** How did architects become involved?
>   **Cobb:** Someone had to design the dreams.
>  (to Arthur) Let’s go another five minutes— 
>   
>  **Ariadne:** We were only asleep for five minutes? We talked for an hour at least. . .
>    **Cobb:** When you dream, your mind functions more quickly, so time seems to pass more slowly.
>    **Arthur:**  Five minutes in the real world gives you an hour in a dream.
>   **Cobb:** Why don't you see ***how much trouble you can cause*** in five minutes.
> <sub>Source: [Movie script - *Inception* (2010) [.pdf]](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/Screenplay-Inception.pdf), hosted by the [Drexel Screenplay Library](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~ina22/splaylib/dwpscreenplay-library.htm#I)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The [definition of "get up to"](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/get-up-to) from the MacMillan dictionary might be more helpful:

> to do something, especially something that you should not do

In the context, it seems like the person is saying *"I'll give you five real world minutes. Why don't you go see how much mischief you could cause in a dream during that time?"*